# He is the best soccer player "on" his team. vs He is the best soccer player "in" his team

Tags: prepositions, superlatives

> - He is the best soccer player **on** his team.
> - He is the best soccer player **in** his team

Are both preposition correct?
I learned that when we make superlative expresstion, we usually use preposition in or of.
For example, she is the most beautiful girl in the world.
So I wonder if it is right to use other perepositions in superlative expresstion.

Comment: Which do you think is right? And why?

Comment: To be clear, you are asking about **IN** and **ON**, right? You can [edit] your post to include more details or make clarifications.

Comment: Please note: soccer is AmE; BrE uses football.

Comment: @Lambie : a good general point, for amusement only : as boy in England, at a Ruby-playing school we referred to soccer and rugger, "soccer" being an abbreviation for Association Football as opposed to to Rugby Football.

Comment: @djna Well, personally, I'm all for rugby (over say, AmE football). But I've also personally have never said rugby football. Is it necessary?

Comment: @Lambie I too would normally say only "Rugby" and on occasion perhaps "Rugby Union" or "Rugby League". I see that the England team website refers to itself as  the site for England Rugby, and if we dig a little deeper we see references to the formal governing body the "Rugby Football Union". My conclusion: necessary only for formality. Now, Gaelic Football ...

Comment: @djna Yes, official names for sure. Let's not forget Australian footie. :) My opinion is that if you're gonna play macho, play rugby not the sissy-footed Am football. (I am American by the way).

Answer (score 2):

> **He is the best Soccer  player in his  team**.
>
> **He is the best soccer player on his team**.

The  link I have provided  shows  that  both  are correct.

According  to  the  link  Americans  usually  say  **on  the  team** and  British say **in  the  team**

https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/170446-On-the-team-vs-in-the-team

Comment: Best footballer in the team versus best soccer player on the team.